# How Could I Select a vertex by its ID?

Tags: python, vertices

How could I select one vertex from my mesh if I know ID of that vertex? I enabled `bpy.app.debug = True` and I can see all IDs but cant find a specific one.

Comment: do you mean index ?

Comment: Yup, Im not sure whats the correct term, you can call it index, select vertex by number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here the answere:

```
import bpy
import bmesh


index = 0 # here the index you want select please change 

obj = bpy.context.object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

vertices= [e for e in bm.verts]
oa = bpy.context.active_object

for vert in vertices:
    if vert.index == index:
        vert.select = True
    else:
        vert.select = False

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

Comment: Tnx, this is working just perfect

Comment: I added more then one number in index with comma but it does not work, what else do I need to change :)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add to yhoyos answer, that a vertex can be selected by replacing the for-loop with

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bm.verts[index].select = True
```

Also, if you don't care about the previous selections, just using

```
bm.verts[index].select = True
```

should be significantly faster for large meshes

Comment: Agree re no need for for loop. Btw it's `bm.verts` and will need to `bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()` to access via index, and maybe add the check `abs(index) < len(bm.verts)`