# Select vertices by their indices (by vertex id)

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, vertices, bmesh

I want to select vertices by their indices (by vertex id)
Like a python script,so that i can write the vertex id into it, and run the script,and it would automatically select those vertices

there is already an answer (python script) ,but it only works with one vertex
when i tried with more than 2 vertices,it does not work :
[How Could I Select a vertex by its ID?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28109/how-could-i-select-a-vertex-by-its-id)

Answer (score 5):

I have modified the code from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28110/5113) to solve the problem, where I have replaced  `if vert.index == index:` to `if vert.index in indices:` where `indices= [1, 2, ...]`

example :

```
import bpy
import bmesh

indices = [1, 3, 4, 7, 8] 

obj = bpy.context.object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

vertices= [e for e in bm.verts]
oa = bpy.context.active_object

for vert in vertices:
    if vert.index in indices:
        vert.select = True
    else:
        vert.select = False

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

Comment: Another approach would be to remove the `else: vert.select=False` so that it only extends the selection, then manually de-select all if you want to start again.

Comment: same thing for the faces? face in faces ?

Comment: For blender 3.2 version, it seems the `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True) ` should change to `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me) `